# How do I make my iPod 5 gen stop asking for my Apple ID password to update an app?

Tags: ipod-touch, ios-appstore

The other day I went to update Pandora so I could listen to music and once I press update it asks for Apple ID password.
This does this to all of my other apps that must be updated.

Comment: I don't think you can. Touch ID on the newer devices makes that easier. That was something that changed as of iOS 7 and seemed to get worse in iOS 8. I agree that it is inconvenient.

Comment: I believe the latest iOS 8.3 is the first to introduce the option to be able to update and download free apps without entering a password each time.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand the question, the app store hasn't asked me for a password to _update_ an app since automatic updates came around  ( circa iOS7? ).   I do know that if you downloaded apps using one appleid, then later changed the appleid for app store (settings > iTunes and app store) it asks for a password when an app downloaded under the previous appleid wants to update.

Answer (score 1):

Agree with @Tyson, updates do not require a password in recent versions of iOS, presuming you are signed into the App Store with the account that originally purchased (or acquired) the app.

If you have multiple accounts, and each account has downloaded one or more apps, you are always going to be prompted for the password if the account that is signed in is not the same one as the account that purchased the app that you are trying to update.

It sounds like in your case you might have changed Apple IDs, or used somebody else's when originally acquiring the apps? In which case, you can sign out of the store (App Store > first tab > "Sign Out [your email]" at the bottom) and sign back in with the account that acquired the apps you are trying to update.